# How to make jenkins HA?

Tags: jenkins, high-availability, gearman

I have two physical servers(Ab and Bb) for batch. Each of them runs separately with its own Jenkins Master. What I want to do is make HA environment for them. If Ab died, then Bb could start Jenkins master role(i.e. Ab is Jenkins master and Bb is Jenkins slave).

I found Gearman Plugin could help make HA environment. I designed HA environment by using it and made new server for Gearman(let it Gs). Other article said using multi master, so I installed Gearman plugin both for Ab and Bb and connect them to Gs. I enrolled same jobs to Ab master and Bb master but it runs separately(it means run doubly). For solving this problem, I tried share $JENKINS_HOME by NFS, but it evoke error too. Could you give me any advice for solving this situation?

Or **other solutions for making HA environment using Jenkins** is really good.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

cloudbees has a good article on it. Link below:-

https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-install-guide/#high-availability

Comment: Thank you for reply. But cloudbees platform need to pay, so I want to find free solution.